# windows socket multithreading I/O Completion ports

Tags: windows, multithreading, sockets

I wrote a windows socket server with I/O Completion port to handle heavy data transmission. It works smoothly when there is only one client connected. when more than one client connect, other threads just seem blocked while only one thread works fine.

I changed my design to use select() with each thread for each connection, the problem seems still the same. By the way, the same design works fine in OSX.

However, when I run multiple instances of my process, a process serves each connection, it works great.

Anyone kind enough to enlighten me? I still prefer multithread design. Core code as following:

other part of code basically comes from: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13382/A-simple-application-using-I-O-Completion-Ports-an

```
//Worker thread will service IOCP requests
DWORD WINAPI WorkerThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{    
    int nThreadNo = (int)lpParam;

    void *lpContext = NULL;
    OVERLAPPED       *pOverlapped = NULL;
    CClientContext   *pClientContext = NULL;
    DWORD            dwBytesTransfered = 0;
    int nBytesRecv = 0;
    int nBytesSent = 0;
    DWORD             dwBytes = 0, dwFlags = 0;

    //Worker thread will be around to process requests, until a Shutdown event is not Signaled.
    while (WAIT_OBJECT_0 != WaitForSingleObject(g_hShutdownEvent, 0))
    {
        BOOL bReturn = GetQueuedCompletionStatus(
            g_hIOCompletionPort,
            &dwBytesTransfered,
            (LPDWORD)&lpContext,
            &pOverlapped,
            INFINITE);

        //WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: GetQueuedCompletionStatus.", nThreadNo);


        if (NULL == lpContext)
        {
            //We are shutting down
            break;
        }

        //Get the client context
        pClientContext = (CClientContext *)lpContext;

        if ((FALSE == bReturn) || ((TRUE == bReturn) && (0 == dwBytesTransfered)))
        {
            //Client connection gone, remove it.
            RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);
            continue;
        }

        WSABUF *p_wbuf = pClientContext->GetWSABUFPtr();
        OVERLAPPED *p_ol = pClientContext->GetOVERLAPPEDPtr();

        switch (pClientContext->GetOpCode())
        {
        case OP_READ:
            pClientContext->SetTransLen(dwBytesTransfered);
            if(!pClientContext->IsComplete())
            {
                pClientContext->SetOpCode(OP_READ);

                dwFlags = 0;

                //Overlapped send
                nBytesSent = WSASend(pClientContext->GetSocket(), p_wbuf, 1, 
                    &dwBytes, dwFlags, p_ol, NULL);

                WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: WSASend continue bytes = %d.", nThreadNo, dwBytes);

                if ((SOCKET_ERROR == nBytesSent) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                {
                    //Let's not work with this client
                    RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);

                    WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: WSASend failed.", nThreadNo);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                WriteToConsole("\nsocket %d: WSASend complete.", pClientContext->GetSocket());

                //clear cache
                pClientContext->ResetWSABUF();

                //for the next recv, must be triggered.
                pClientContext->SetOpCode(OP_WRITE);
                //Get the data.
                nBytesRecv = WSARecv(pClientContext->GetSocket(), p_wbuf, 1, 
                    &dwBytes, &dwFlags, p_ol, NULL);

                if ((SOCKET_ERROR == nBytesRecv) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                {
                    WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: Error occurred while executing WSARecv().", nThreadNo);

                    //Let's not work with this client
                    RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);
                }
            }

            break;

        case OP_WRITE:
            pClientContext->SetTransLen(dwBytesTransfered);
            if(pClientContext->IsComplete())
            {
                if(!pClientContext->ProcessCmd())
                {
                    WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: ProcessCmd failed.", nThreadNo);
                    //Let's not work with this client
                    RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);
                }

                WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: receive completed.", nThreadNo);

                //Send the message back to the client.
                pClientContext->SetOpCode(OP_READ);

                dwFlags = 0;

                //Overlapped send
                nBytesSent = WSASend(pClientContext->GetSocket(), p_wbuf, 1, 
                    &dwBytes, dwFlags, p_ol, NULL);

                WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: WSASend bytes = %d.", nThreadNo, dwBytes);

                if ((SOCKET_ERROR == nBytesSent) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                {
                    WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: Error occurred while executing WSASend().", nThreadNo);

                    //Let's not work with this client
                    RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);
                }
            }
            else    //continue receiving
            {
                pClientContext->SetOpCode(OP_WRITE);
                //Get the data.
                nBytesRecv = WSARecv(pClientContext->GetSocket(), p_wbuf, 1, 
                    &dwBytes, &dwFlags, p_ol, NULL);

                WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: WSARecv continue bytes = %d.", nThreadNo, dwBytes);

                if ((SOCKET_ERROR == nBytesRecv) && (WSA_IO_PENDING != WSAGetLastError()))
                {
                    WriteToConsole("\nThread %d: Error occurred while executing WSARecv().", nThreadNo);

                    //Let's not work with this client
                    RemoveFromClientListAndFreeMemory(pClientContext);
                }
            }




            break;

        default:
            //We should never be reaching here, under normal circumstances.
            break;
        } // switch
    } // while

    return 0;
}
```

Updates: since my server app need to send large amount of data to multiple clients, it works fine maybe for some minutes, but somehow for no reason, some threads just block without responding. Does it have anything to do with the size of data?

Comment: welcome to SO ! please share your code and more specific issues in order to get meaningful help

Comment: Yeah, code pls.  You are doing something very wrong:(   IOCP on Windows works very well.

Comment: You say "other threads just seem blocked while only one thread works fine" ... so do you mean that it is all working except that only one thread is processing the requests?  Because that's perfectly normal under light load.  By design, IOCP always uses as few threads as are necessary.

Comment: Thanks, Harry. That's not the case. The fact is: while two clients connect, one client might be served very well, but the other one seems to be blocked which it should be served. So far, I still don't have a clue. Thank you again.

Comment: @Luaan - It's perfectly normal to have your I/O processing threads block on `GetQueuedCompletionStatus()`, that's THE POINT of how IOCP works. You have a pool of threads calling GQCS and the IOCP manages releasing them to do work for you as completions arrive. You then loop back around and wait for more work.

Comment: You might like to look at a different CodeProject example for a starting point as, perhaps, the problems are with the example you based your code on rather than your code. I wrote this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2336/A-reusable-high-performance-socket-server-class-Pa back in 2000 and it works pretty well and has no open bug reports.

Comment: @LenHolgate  Many thanks, Len. I did notice your article on CodeProject, just haven't got time to read it carefully. I did a little more research this couple of days. Microsoft did have a support article claimed that using WSASend to send large data does cause slow performance. Some sources suggest that TransmitFile() and TransmitPackets() may be better replacements. Really appreciate if you can shed me some light. thanks.

Comment: @Steve, `WSASend()` works just fine. I've been writing IOCP clients and servers for something like 13 years now and I've never had a problem with `WSASend()` and 'large' data; you may need to roll your own 'flow control' to avoid swamping the network stack and, perhaps, `TransmitFile()` does that kind of stuff under the covers, but IMHO switching API calls won't fix your problem.

Comment: @LenHolgate My bad, I looked at this the wrong way. The CP article OP linked has very little error handling and doesn't really handle cleanup at all. That's probably causing Steve's issues.

Comment: One bug in the code you've posted: if `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` fails, then `pClientContext` is invalid, but you use it anyway.  Probably not your current problem, but FYI.

Comment: You need more information on what's happening.  Additional diagnostic output might help, as might stepping through the flow of control with a debugger.  In either case I suggest that you start only a single worker thread, to simplify the problem.

Comment: @All. Thanks to all of you who are so kind to offer help. I just discovered that the bug doesn't actually originate from the code above or the example my code based on. It's from another part of my code which might wait on a invalid thread handle. Thanks again. guy. best regards!